# Color Assign kendo chart

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have two `dataseries` and want to give different colors as follows. However no matter I assign different color, I am ending up with same color which is color of the last series (#006666).

```
 self.dataSeries[0].color = "#66FF66";
 self.dataSeries[1].color = "#006666";
 chart.options.series = self.dataSeries;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way you do it,

1. first acess **kendo chart > options > series[index] > color**, then give the color you want
2. refresh the kendo chart

Here code example :

```
$("#chart").data("kendoChart").options.series[0].color = "#66FF66";
$("#chart").data("kendoChart").options.series[1].color = "#006666";
$("#chart").data("kendoChart").refresh();
```

> [DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/OdoZo)

Note : There is a chart and a button **assign new color** to change the series color